# Perl or any script to fail-over solace VPN's between Data centers

Tags: solace

I have multiple VPN's in solace appliance. we need to fail-over all VPN's at same time from Production to DR data centers. do we have any in-build script that can I use or suggest me how to develop the script.

Thanks,
Ramesh

Answer (score 0):

A controlled replication switch-over is intended to be a manual activity so there is no built-in script to complete the activity. It is intended to be manual as it is required to wait until replication queue is fully drained until completing the switch-over. If the message VPNs are using XA transactions, it may also be required to heuristically roll back or commit any prepared transactions that were on a formally active site.

The steps to perform a controlled switch-over are below. In the example, it is assumed that NY_Appliance1 as the initially active appliance and NJ_Appliance1 as the initially standby appliance. The example shows only one message VPN named Trading_VPN, but the steps must be repeated for each message VPN. If multiple VPNs need to be switched-over at the same time, it may be easier to use SolAdmin or the Solace WebUI.

1. Verify that the replication bridge is bound to the replication queue:
   Run "show message-vpn Trading_VPN replication" on each replication site. The remote bridge state should be "Up" for the replication-active site and the local bridge state should be "Up" for the replication-standby site

   ```
   NY_Appliance1> show message-vpn Trading_VPN replication

     Message VPN                      A C B R Q S M T
     -------------------------------- - - - - - - - - -
     Trading_VPN                      U A - U U - N A

   NJ_Appliance1> show message-vpn Trading_VPN replication

     Message VPN                      A C B R Q S M T
     -------------------------------- - - - - - - - - -
     Trading_VPN                      U S U - - - N A
   ```
2. Switch the currently replication active Message VPNs to standby.

   ```
   NY_Appliance1(configure)# message-vpn Trading_VPN 
   NY_Appliance1(configure/message-vpn)# replication state standby
   ```

   Repeat for each Message VPN.
3. Allow any messages or transactions that are in progress from the formerly replication active Message VPN to its corresponding Message VPN on its replication mate to arrive . Allowing the propagation of all messages and transactions to the standby Message VPN can prevent the loss of asynchronous replication messages and transactions.

   ```
   NY_Appliance1(configure)# show queue #MSGVPN_REPLICATION_DATA_QUEUE message-vpn Trading_VPN

     Name                                 : #MSGVPN_REPLICATION_DATA_QUEUE
     Message VPN                          : Trading_VPN
     ...
     Current Messages Spooled             : 1
     Current Spool Usage (MB)             : 0.0006
     ...
   ```

   The system administrator should not configure the Message VPN in the other replication mate (NJ_Appliance1) as replication active until “Current Messages Spooled” is 0 for the replication queue for the Message VPN that was just switched to replication standby.
4. If the Message VPN is using XA transactions, there may be some prepared transactions on the formerly active site that need to be heuristically committed or rolled back. Only prepared transactions have to be addressed. Transactions in other states can be ignored.

   In order to appropriately decide if the XA transaction should be committed or rolled back, the user should check the logs or state of the transaction manager from the application side.

   ```
   NY_Appliance1> show transaction message-vpn Trading_VPN state PREPARED replicated detail
   ```
5. Switch the formerly replication-standby message VPN to replication-active

   ```
   NJ_Appliance1(configure)# message-vpn Trading_VPN
   NJ_Appliance1(configure/message-vpn)# replication state active
   ```

   Repeat for each message VPN.
6. If you previously heuristically completed transactions, you should delete them to free up the resources. You must always delete the completed transactions on the formerly active site.

   ```
   solace(admin/message-spool) delete-transaction xid <xid>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the details steps.

my concern is I have around 300 VPN's. if I follow manual processes it will take more than 15 hours to fail-over all. so I am looking the alternate way to fail-over that can save my time.

Thanks,
Ramesh